# TypeConverters not working for Collections in @Query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I've an entity called Events which is defined as follows:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Events")
data class Event(@PrimaryKey val id: Long, val name: String, val venues: Set<String>, val rating: Int)
```

I've a pair of `@TypeConverter` methods for handling `Set<String>`:

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromStringToStringSet(str: String): Set<String> = str.split("<|>")

@TypeConverter
fun fromStringSetToString(set: Set<String>): String = set.joinToString("<|>")
```

In my `Dao`, I've a method annotated with `@Query` as follows:

```
@Query("UPDATE Events SET name = :name, venues = :venues WHERE id = :id")
fun updateAndRetainRating(id: Long, name: String, venues: Set<String>)
```

When I try to update an event with 2 venues, I get a runtime error telling me that the SQL couldn't be compiled. The generated SQL is:

```
UPDATE Events SET name = ?, venues = ?,? WHERE id = ?
```

This is obviously wrong. Looking into the generated code, Room is getting the size of `Set<String>` and adding the same number of `?`s.

Why isn't my `TypeConverter` being used? I don't face this issue in other queries(`@Insert` and `@Query`(for `SELECT`)). Other `TypeConverter`s are also working fine.

EDIT: The same issue also occurs if I use `List<String>` + `TypeConverter`s instead of `Set<String>`.

Comment: This issue occurs with both `androidx` versions `2.1.0-alpha04` and `2.1.0-alpha05`.

Comment: Off-topic: Set doesn't guarantee ordering. One time you may get `Wembley|LBC` other time `LBC|Wembley`. Good luck debugging that. Maybe wrap venues in a custom object which will handle ordering.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Ordering isn't important for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the Room documentation, it appears that whenever we use a `Collection` in `@Query`, it bypasses `TypeConverter`s and is straight away flattened.

For example, this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE city IN (:cities)")
fun getCustomersInCities(cities: List<String>): Flowable<List<Customer>>
```

results in `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE city IN ('london', 'paris')` if `cities` contains "london" and "paris".

Unfortunately, the following is also converted in a similar way:

```
@Query("UPDATE Customers SET phoneNumbers = :phoneNumbers WHERE id = :id")
fun updateCustomerPhoneNumbers(id: Long, phoneNumbers: List<String>)
```

The result is `UPDATE Customers SET phoneNumbers = 1234567890, 9876543210 WHERE id = 23` if `id` is 23 and the `phoneNumbers` contains "1234567890" and "9876543210".

While this does make sense, it is really inconvenient and should be documented more clearly.

Comment: I'm not accepting this answer since this doesn't solve the issue. If someone comes up with a better solution, I'll accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:
[TypeConverter not working when updating List<Boolean> in Room Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938256/typeconverter-not-working-when-updating-listboolean-in-room-database)

Basically, replace `List<String>` by `ArrayList<String>`.